# Problema de scroll en los grid

Tags: html, css

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]tengo unos `div` con unos grid y el problema viene cuando el scoll me baja mas que donde terminan los `div`. No entiendo porque se me alarga el scroll si debajo ya no hay nada...

```css
.grid2 {
    
  margin-top:5%;
  height: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(30%, 30%);
  grid-gap: 15px;
}
.grid-item {
    overflow: hidden;
  border: 3px solid green;
    border-radius: 12px;
}
 .container3 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid2">
      <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="imagen">
        <img src="gavacho.jpeg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Prèssec Gabacho</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed nostrum modi quis assumenda ad? Asperiores nisi eligendi rem ea soluta natus nostrum vitae aliquam, officiis, suscipit, exercitationem pariatur quae doloremque.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
          <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="imagen">
        <img src="gavacho.jpeg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Prèssec Gabacho</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed nostrum modi quis assumenda ad? Asperiores nisi eligendi rem ea soluta natus nostrum vitae aliquam, officiis, suscipit, exercitationem pariatur quae doloremque.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
          <div class="grid-item">
    <div class="container3">
      <div class="imagen">
        <img src="gavacho.jpeg" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <h2>Prèssec Gabacho</h2>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed nostrum modi quis assumenda ad? Asperiores nisi eligendi rem ea soluta natus nostrum vitae aliquam, officiis, suscipit, exercitationem pariatur quae doloremque.
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
      </div>
```

Comment: El problema es el `grid-auto-rows`. Prueba de cambiar el valor con _px_ a esto `grid-auto-rows: minmax(30%,100px);`

Comment: En el ejemplo de código que pones no ocurre eso

Answer (score 1):

> *Por debajo no hay nada en la vista*...

Bueno a la vista no, pero si ha ocupado el contenido que tienes, vemos la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces mi solución es en vez de usar `grid-auto-rows` he usado `grid-template-rows`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así desaparece el scroll no deseado.

```css
.grid2 {    
  margin-top:5%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 70px 1fr; /* !!! */
  
  /* Si quieres que cambie de tamaño vertical 
  
  grid-template-rows: 30vh 1fr;
  */
  
  grid-gap: 15px;
}
.grid-item {
  overflow: hidden; /* auto si quieres scroll */
  border: 3px solid green;
  border-radius: 12px;
}
 .container3 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid2">
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="container3">
        <div class="imagen">
          <img src="gavacho.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Prèssec Gabacho</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed nostrum modi quis assumenda ad? Asperiores nisi eligendi rem ea soluta natus nostrum vitae aliquam, officiis, suscipit, exercitationem pariatur quae doloremque.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="container3">
        <div class="imagen">
          <img src="gavacho.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Prèssec Gabacho</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed nostrum modi quis assumenda ad? Asperiores nisi eligendi rem ea soluta natus nostrum vitae aliquam, officiis, suscipit, exercitationem pariatur quae doloremque.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="grid-item">
      <div class="container3">
        <div class="imagen">
          <img src="gavacho.jpeg" />
        </div>
        <div>
          <h2>Prèssec Gabacho</h2>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sed nostrum modi quis assumenda ad? Asperiores nisi eligendi rem ea soluta natus nostrum vitae aliquam, officiis, suscipit, exercitationem pariatur quae doloremque.
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
```

Comment: no es lo que yo digo, te hago captura de pantalla y ves a lo que me refiero.Mira la pregunta y veras que inserto la captura.

Comment: Pero haz visto en el ejemplo que he puesto que no se hace scroll poniendo `grid-template-rows`? Y que no hay espacio bajo de las cajas?